# Garbage values are printed when I try to print the elements of an array using pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, pointers

I have a class named mvector which has two private variables, num (denotes number of elements in the array), and an integer pointer to store the array address. 
mvector has 2 public functions, get() and print() to get the elements of the array, and print them (respectively).
However, when I try to print the values, some values are correct, while others are garbage values.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class mvector
{
    private:
        int num;
        int *ele;
    public:
        void get();
        void print();
};

void mvector::get()
{
    cin>>num;
    int data[num];
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        cin>>data[i];
    }

    ele=data;
}

void mvector::print()
{
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        cout<<*ele<<endl;
        ele++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    mvector v1;
    v1.get();
    v1.print();

}


Input: 5 1 2 3 4 5
Expected Output: 1 2 3 4 5
Actual Output: 1 1 1877615960 4 5
```

Comment: This code      cin>>num;
    int data[num]; is not a standard C++ code And the program has undefined behavior because there is used pointer with an invalid value.

Comment: Using `data` outside of `get() ` triggers undefined behavior

Comment: Then how should i proceed?

Comment: The problem is that you are creating your array `data[num]` inside `get()` as a local variable and it will get destroyed once the `get()` function ends. So at the end `ele`is pointing to a memory location that is not claimed by any variable anymore and might have been replaced with garbage values. Thus you have dangling pointer now. Use the `new` keyword while creating new memory allocations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
ele=data;
```

is the source of your problems.

`data` is a local array, a non-standard VLA, but it is still a local array. When the function returns `data` is destructed and `ele` points to an object that is no longer valid. Accessing `ele` after the function returns is cause for undefined behavior. The garbage values you are seeing is just one symptom of undefined behavior.

You can change that function to use:

```
void mvector::get()
{
    cin>>num;
    ele = new int[num];
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        cin>>ele[i];
    }
}
```

That will solve your immediate problem. However, there are other issues you have to contend with when managing memory yourself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three for additional details.

Answer (score 2):

The program does not make a great sense.

For example the variable length arrays is not standard C++ feature. So the declaration of the array

```
cin>>num;
int data[num];
```

is not correct.

Within the function `get` the  data member `ele` is assigned with the address of the first element of a local array that will not be alive after exiting the member function. So using this pointer in the member function `print` invokes undefined behavior.

You have to define the array dynamically.

Moreover within the function `print` the pointer `ele` is incremented and loses its initial value. It means that you could call the function the second time

You should define a class with constructors and destructor.

More or less working code can look the following way.

```
#include <iostream>

class mvector
{
    private:
        size_t num = 0;
        int *ele = nullptr;
    public:
        void get();
        void print() const;
};

void mvector::get()
{
    size_t n;
    std::cin >> n;

    if ( n != num )
    {
        delete [] ele;
        ele = nullptr;

        if ( n != 0 )
        {
            ele = new int[n];
        }

        num = n;
    }

    if ( num != 0 )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            std::cin >> ele[i];
        }
    }
}

void mvector::print() const
{
    int *p = ele;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < num; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << *p << ' ';
        ++p;
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    mvector v1;

    v1.get();
    v1.print();

    v1.get();
}
```

For the input like this

```
5 
1 2 3 4 5 
0
```

The output will be

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

and the allocated memory will be freed.